Mapping does not work in "Press ENTER or type command to continue" screen only on macOS
Assume this setup:

Start Vim via command vim -u NONE -N.

Execute nnoremap <C-e> :!echo hello<CR> to create a mapping. This mapping means, when I press Ctrl-e, it runs the shell command echo hello.

By the way, please note the default behavior of Ctrl-e is to scroll the buffer by one line. This behavior is overridden by the mapping above.



Given the setup, when I press Ctrl-e, the shell command is executed and the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" screen is shown as expected:

After that, the behaviors are inconsistent between macOS and Linux:
Linux (Vim 9.1, patches 1-689, SSH-ed from macOS' iTerm2.app)
When I repeatedly press Ctrl-e, the shell command is repeatedly executed WITHOUT making me leave the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" screen:

macOS (Vim 9.1, patches 1-750, iTerm2.app)
When I press Ctrl-e while I'm on the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" screen, the shell command is NOT executed. Instead, I'm moved back to the buffer for some reason and the buffer is scrolled by one line, which is the default behavior of Ctrl-e without mapping:

But why? I want to repeatedly execute the command also on macOS.

It seems this is a bug of the terminal emulator I'm using: iTerm2.app.
The OP is exactly the same as the issue Keyboard shortcuts in Vim require shift key to work opened 4 years ago (and still open).
Writing the commands below in ~/.vimrc solved the problem:
let &t_TI = ""
let &t_TE = ""

For the details, see the link above and :help modifyOtherKeys.
